# delete multiple substrings from a string in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I know that the following deletes four characters starting with position 3 in the string in question ('12345678') in Delphi:

```
    var
      Source : string;

    begin
      Source := '12345678';
      delete(Source, 3, 4);    // Delete the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th characters
      ShowMessage('Source now : '+Source);
    end;
```

But how do I delete multiple substrings? For example, if I wanted to delete 2 & 3 as well as 5 & 6 in the string '12345678' so as to get '1478.' Thanks.

Comment: Delete two characters starting at 5 and then delete two characters starting at 2; Two lines of code.

Comment: So it does require two lines. Thanks.

Comment: Source:=copy(Source,1,1) + copy(Source,4,1) + copy(Source,7,MaxInt);

Comment: That's a nice alternative! I like that. I also learned MaxInt. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that the solution suggested by @JanLauridsen results in three additional temporary string allocations (in addition to the original `Source` one) that don't exist in the two-line solution. Saving a line of code isn't always the best solution.

Comment: Not to mention the overhead of three function calls (the three calls to `Copy`).

Comment: Sometimes it's the clarity that matters. The problem with using Delete here is that after the first call, the indices have shifted. Which is why Ken suggested working from right to left. One might argue that the Copy version was easier to read.

Comment: @Serge, `copy(Source,7,MaxInt)` is best written `copy(Source,7)`.

Comment: @LURD: Depends on the Delphi version. Older versions didn't default the last parameter, so you had to pass it. Using MaxInt works in all versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (and probably most efficient) way is simply to do it with two calls to `Delete`, first to delete two characters starting at 5 and then to delete two characters starting at 2. (If you start with 2 first, it shifts the indices for the remaining characters, as David pointed out in a comment to the question).

```
var
  Source : string;
begin
  Source := '12345678';
  Delete(Source, 5, 2);  
  Delete(Source, 2, 2); 
  ShowMessage('Source now : '+Source);
end;
```

@JanLaundsen suggested in a comment to the question that you can also use `Copy` to do it in one line:

```
Source := Copy(Source, 1, 1) + Copy(Source, 4, 1) + Copy(Source, 7, MaxInt);
```

This solution works, but adds the overhead of three function calls (the calls to `Copy`) plus three temporary string allocations (one for the result of each call to `Copy`) that do not happen in the two line calls to `Delete`. (Saving a line of code isn't always the best solution). IMO, the two separate calls are also much easier to read, but that's a personal opinion. It may not be more readable to you.

Comment: It's possible to do this with a single memory reallocation, so two Deletes won't be the most efficient. Not that I think it matters very much, just the mathematician in me coming to the fore.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: OK. I said *probably*, not *absolutely*. I made it community-wiki; if it bothers you, fee free to edit to take it out. It's definitely more efficient than the Copy technique.

Comment: I seem to have set off an interesting discussion among the experts. Honestly, I am happy to get all your inputs, as they work. I can see that two lines of delete (with yes, the downstream fragment before the upstream one; I caught that clever code yesterday - thanks @Ken). I am happy to see my programs work at this point. I hope to master coding enough one day to worry about efficiency. Thanks again.

Comment: I finished my program and everything is working fine, including the deletion of substring(s) using the solution of @Ken above, except for one small weird detail. The deletion is one character off. For example, if it is supposed to delete characters 100 to 110, it is deleting characters 99 to 109. So I added +1 to the code (e.g., 5+1 in the first delete line of his code above). But then it deletes characters 101 to 111. Any idea why?

Comment: @Serge: That's impossible. What Delphi version are you using? What OS are you building for?

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but that's what has been happening and it's driving me nuts. This is on a machine running Windows 7 Enterprise and the version is Delphi XE.

Comment: As I said, what you describe is impossible. You've got an index out of place or out of order. This could only happen if you've deleted the lower piece first before the higher (which I pointed out in my answer you cannot do because it alters the indices).

Comment: Also, I didn't ask what OS your machine is running - I asked which OS you're *building for* (Win32, Win64, OS X, iOS, Android).

Comment: Win32. The line simply says "delete(Line, Start, Cut);" and I have checked the values of all three variables by hovering over them (and using a watchlist) - and all of them are correct. Used this way, I get characters 99-109 taken off, and if I change it to "delete(Line, Start+1, Cut);", I get 101-111 deleted. So there is no index to get wrong, and so I am at a loss to know which part of the code to look for the problem. And yes, I have followed your solution by deleting the second before the first. But this happens even when there is a single substring to delete.

Comment: Can't help, I'm afraid, because what you describe is simply not possible. If you can provide details to reproduce it (an actual, reasonable length string and the code that is failing exactly as you describe), post a new question that includes those details so we can look at it. Put it into a console application, so there is no user interface clutter, in a form we can copy, paste and compile. (Note it should be a *new question* and not an edit to this one.)